# Show object names in viewport render

Tags: 3d-view

I'm using Blender 2.92
I have 26 objects in my scene which I've enabled 'Show: Name' under the Viewport Display settings of the Object Properties tab. The names appear ok in the viewport display but they disappear when I do a Render Viewport Animation. I'd like them to remain visible for this but I can't seem to get the settings right to do this. Is it possible? Or do I have to do the tedious task of creating 26 x Text Objects and aligning them to the camera?

Comment: No not quite. I did see that post, however my interpretation was that user wanted the name labels to appear in a final render (ie. using the cycles or Eevee render engine etc). I'm just trying to get them to appear in a simple viewport render (Open GL I think?). If they can appear in the 3D viewport I don't see why they couldn't appear when creating a viewport render.